# Fake can't handle if

Tags: c#, build-script

I have a WPF Project, which I build with FAKE. However, since I am using C# Elements like

```
if (value is Datatype variable){
    //CODE
}
```

I am no longer able to build the Program but from VS I can run it. I think the Problem is that I use a newer Compiler Version in VS. Can I Change the Compiler Version from FAKE or can I force my build-script to use a specific Version. I have tried to remove these Features to check if the Problem is really on this Syntax.

Comment: I have also tried to install the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package

Comment: "_...am no longer able to build..._" What errors do you get?

Comment: As Kevin Smith wrote I want to use C# 7 Features for the example from my Post when I use the IF expression from I get this exception:
Classname.cs(13,46): error CS1026: ) expected
Classname. cs(13,60): error CS1002: ; expected
Classname .cs(13,60): error CS1513: } expected

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using some C# 7 features and FAKE is not running MSBuild with language version of 7, add the following to your csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It will force the compiler to use the latest language version

Comment: This didn't worke for me. At the Moment i have just removed this language Features.